# Changing default named options per scope

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Using .NET Core's dependency injection `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, I'd like to change the `IOptions<>` that are passed to a service based on information that I have available when creating a scope, i.e. at runtime, rather than based on any configuration that I can apply during start up (that I'm aware of).

For example, in my `Startup.cs`, I have the following named options configured:

```cs
services.Configure<SomeOptions>("red", config.GetSection("MyOptions:Red"));
services.Configure<SomeOptions>("blue", config.GetSection("MyOptions:Blue"));
```

I have some code that creates a scope in order to do some work:

```cs
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

// …

using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    // Some incoming request that should determine which colour to use.
    var request = new { Colour = "red" };

    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeService>();

    service.DoYourThing();
}
```

Here `SomeService` consumes options of type `SomeOptions`:

```cs
public SomeService(IOptions<SomeOptions> options)
{
    public void DoYourThing()
    {
        // …
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass either the "red" or "blue" options to `SomeService`, rather than requiring `SomeService` to look up the correct version of the options via `IOptionsSnapshot<T>.Get(string)`. Whilst I can use an `IOptionsSnapshot<SomeOptions>`, I don't want to do this in all services that require these "colour dependent" settings, I'd rather they didn't have this responsibility, and I don't want to litter my code with this repeated logic (plus the repeated logic of handling missing colours etc).

Ideally, at the point that I create a scope, I'd like to be able say which of the named options should be the default options for this type.

Is there some service or options pattern I can adopt that would achieve what I'm looking for here?

Comment: So if I understand your scenario correctly, you’d like `request.Colour` to be a parameter into how the service provider constructs the dependencies for `SomeService`? Effectively you need a way for the correct named options instance to be selected and injected?

Comment: @MattBrooks exactly.